# Show if $\operatorname{diam}(A) < r$ $\implies$ $A \subset B_{r}(a)$ for $a \in A$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I've seen this problem mentioned on Math.SE before, but not proved thoroughly. With that said I wanted to attempt it for myself and have my work verified.

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset M$. If $\operatorname{diam}(A) < r$, show that $A \subset B_{r}(a)$ for some $a \in A$.

The proof for this seems pretty short:

Let $a_{o}, b \in A$ and $r > 0$. Since $\operatorname{diam}(A) := \sup\{d(a,b): a, b \in A\} < r$, then $d(a_o,b) < \operatorname{diam}(A) < r$. So since $d(a_{o},b) <r$ by definition of an open ball of radius $r$, $b \in B_{r}(a_{o})$ for some $a_{o} \in A$. Therefore $A \subset B_{r}(a_{o})$.

Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: Almost: you can only conclude that $d(a_0,b)\color{red}{\le}\operatorname{diam}(A)$. With that correction it works (and proves the stronger result that $A\subseteq B(a,r)$ for **any** $a\in A$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - ah, of course! That makes sense. Thank you for your feedback, Brian!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. The only (minor) problem is when you state that $d(a_0,b)<\operatorname{diam}(A)$. This is not true; all you can say is that $d(a_0,b)\leqslant\operatorname{diam}(A)$. It it still follow from this that $d(a_0,b)<r$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, José!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.